# Loading structure from txt file to dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, structure

I have trouble with saving and loading data from .txt file to dynamic array.

My whole program is based on switch statement.
I will only paste here case which is responsible for allocating memory for array and calling function to fill it with structure. And functions for saving and loading data.

Code looks like this

```
case 1:

            system("cls");

            printf("Enter amount of students you want to put in data base\n");
            scanf("%d",&number_of_students);

            student=(data*)malloc(number_of_students*sizeof(data));
            adding_students_to_base( number_of_students); // its a simple functions based on for loop. I don't think that posting it here is necessary 
    break;
```

and functions:

```
void saving_base_to_file(int amount_of_students)
{
   FILE *file;


   system("cls");
   printf("Saving base to file!\n");

   file=fopen("database.txt","wb");
   fprintf(file,"%d",amount_of_students); // function also saves amount of students in base
   fwrite(student,sizeof( data),amount_of_students,file);  
   fclose(file);

   _getch();
   system("cls");
}




void loading_base_from_file()
{
   FILE *file;

   system("cls");
   printf("Reading base from file\n");

   file=fopen("database.txt","rb");

   if (file!= NULL) {
       fscanf(file,"%d",&number_of_students);
       fread(&student,sizeof( data),number_of_students,file);   //number_of_students is global variable
       student=(data*)malloc(number_of_students*sizeof(data));
       fclose(file);
   }
   else
   {
       printf("File does not exist!.\r\n");
       printf("File have to be named ""database.txt"" !!!\n");
   }
   _getch();
   system("cls");
}
```

(Function saving_base_to_file takes number_of_students as input argument.)

Problem appears when i want to use my "loading_base_from_file" function

For example, when i want to save one student with student_id "123456" named "Greg" "Tesla", file contains this:
[database.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxuwr.png). Function saving_base_to_file also saves amount of students in base. But when i start my program again (or do  it in one program run) and try do load data from file, my function "print_base" prints this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Nls.png)

I think that there is a problem with "putting" data into array, but i don't know what exactly is wrong.
Could you tell me why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Using `fscanf/fprintf` and `fread/fwrite` on the same file handle is difficult to not say a bad idea.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in in C!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `student` indicates that it's a pointer. That means when you use the address-of operator `&` on the variable you get the pointer to where the variable is stored, not a pointer to the memory you allocate. The type of `&student` is `data **` not `data *`.

That alone will lead to *undefined behavior* as you write over data somewhere in memory where it should not be, but is not the only problem. The other problem is that you allocate memory for `student` ***after*** you read the data from the file, making `student` point somewhere else completely and also making you lose the data you just read.

***First*** allocate memory, then read into `student` (and not `&student`).

---

There is yet another problem too, and that is you mix text data and binary data. The initial number you read as the number of records in the file will not be correct when you read it, if the first element in the structure contains a value that can be parsed as a textual digit.

You need to `fwrite` the number, and `fread` it back.

Comment: Thanks, case closed!